# Installing Mercurial (hg) on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: bash, mercurial, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bash-on-windows

I'd like to install Mercurial (HG) on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. Though [Mercurial official site](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download) offers download for both Windows and Ubuntu, it does not offer a download for Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (AKA Windows Subsystem for Linux). How can I install Mercurial (HG) for Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, and if possible from Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. Which is the right Ubuntu package and how to install it?

Comment: just `apt-get install mercurial`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install mercurial via `apt`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

If you want a more up-to-date version you can use the mercurial PPA:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mercurial-ppa/releases
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

Comment: To make work on Ubuntu 18.04 I edited the mercurial source file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d then I replaced the word bionic with zesty in the file.

Comment: This is not working for me under WSL2... after all that it tells me `mercurial is already the newest version (5.3.1-1ubuntu1).` but it's obviously NOT the latest version because it refuses to clone a repo due to it having newer features that it doesn't support.